# Any Office 365 REST API(Graph API) to block delivery of certain emails - if its spam

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am exploring an option to see if it's possible to get messages scanned for all mailboxes in an organization (i.e within a domain) and block delivery of certain emails if its spam using Office 365 Mail REST APIs or if there is any other way to easily get these messages.

- I have looked into connector, but that needs to setup own exchange
  server in windows platform, and its ruled out. Hence looking at Graph
  api.
- Secondly, I looked at developing an email gateway, but for that MX
  records need to be updated and its not possible.

I have stuck with my analysis from last couple of weeks. Any pointers would help a lot. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, I am trying to find something similiar too but for now I've found nothing. Did you managed to come across any solution?

Comment: Its not that simple as it looks. We have finally decided to use postfix as MTA(mail transfer agent) and its milter protocol to scan emails. Please check http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html for more details. We have used postfix milter with kafka integration to process emails. Let me know for any additional informations.